# Fixing "error C2065: undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

First off, I'm completely out of my depth here. So the question might be the wrong one to ask, but here goes...

As per the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643122/is-it-possible-to-generate-complex-tones-in-c), I'm trying to compile the bindings for the [Audiere library](http://audiere.sourceforge.net/), which are produced by Harald Fielker and available in the [mailing list archives](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=200710271451.41075.harald.fielker%40web.de).

I've opened the .vcproj file in VC++ Express Edition and it converted it to a solution it could use. I've then gone into the properties and added:

- "C:\Documents and Settings\tdw20\My Documents\audiere-win32\include" to the additional include directories
- "C:\Documents and Settings\tdw20\My Documents\Downloads\audiere-win32\lib" to the additional library directories

Yet I still get "undeclared identifier" errors. The full output is listed [on pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/1663208).

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Difficult to say without downloading the src. Can you show the first few errors and the corresponding lines from the source file where the error occurs.

Comment: If http://audiere.sourceforge.net/audiere-1.9.4-devel-doxygen/ is the source code then you have errors in a file (outputstream.cpp) which isn't listed there.

Comment: Post the code in outputstream.cpp upto and including line 8.

And this is tagged C# because...?

Comment: Hi guys, the first few lines (up to the first error) are listed here: http://pastebin.ca/1664646 @Jon, the source isn't the main audiere package, but rather the bindings, which outputstream.cpp is part of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I can only start to guess, but are you sure the header files are where you anticipate them to be?

Comment: If that were the case, and he had included them, he'd get a file not found error from the preprocessor.  More likely he has not included the necessary header in the source (and after that, your suggestion may still be right).

Answer (score 0):

The `OutputStream` class referenced in *outputstream.cpp* isn't being recognised. As far as i can tell it's defined in the *audiere.h* header file in the audiere project, and the `#include` directive at line 2 of outputstream.cpp should be including that file.

Two things to try in VC++:

1. In line 8  of outputstream.cpp double-click on `OutputStream` and then right-click, and on the context menu select **Go To Definition**. See what file it opens (if any).
2. Right-click line 2 (`#include <audiere.h>`) and select **Open Document...**. Again see if it opens a file.

Actually, just realied you said you added *C:\Documents and Settings\tdw20\My Documents\audiere-win32\include* to the include but it looks to me like *audiere.h* is in a *src* sub-directory of audiere. Also the path you specified for the libs is inconsistent - it has an extra *Downloads dir* in the path. Are both these paths definitely correct? The dir you add to the include path should contain header files such as *audiere.h* and the dir for the libs should contain *.lib* files.

Comment: Thanks Jon. 1 tells me it's not define, 2 opens the file, but the phrase "OutputStream" isn't anywhere within that file. (The lack of Downloads was a typo and changing these paths leads to more immediate errors.)

Comment: BTW, it sounds like VC is picking up the wrong audiere.h. VC will look in the directories in the include path. You can fine-tune this behaviour by reordering these directories. You need to find the audiere.h that does define the OutputStream class and make sure it is in the include path befroe whichever dir contaisn the audiere.h you're currently including.

Comment: I tried compiling outputstream.cpp. Once i added the audiere/src directory to the *C++/General/Additional Include Directories* properties for the project it compiled ok.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to compile outputstream.cpp for the C# binding's libaudieresharpglue.dll.  Did you download Audiere 1.9.4 Win32 binary release?  I actually encountered an issue where I downloaded an old version of Audiere from 2002, I think, and it gave me a ton of trouble until I realized I had the wrong version.

The *only* source file you should need to worry about is `include/audiere.h`.  You'll link against `lib/audiere.lib`, and at runtime your application will need to access `bin/audiere.dll` (which should probably be moved to your executable's directory, on on the DLL path, when you run your executable).