# Easiest way to play audio in an openTK application, using any method

Tags: c#, .net, audio, opentk

My goal here is to be able to play an MP3 in an OpenTK/OpenGL application (.NET but NOT windows forms), being able to stop/play/pause it, access/set the position of the audio file, and have it play to within a few milliseconds of when I tell it to.

I've tried using WindowsMediaPlayer (WMPLib) but for whatever reason the audio doesn't start playing until I resize or move the window.  Not sure why but it probably has something to do with the fact that it's meant to be a control on Windows Forms, and this is a GL application.

I've tried using .NET's soundplayer but that incurs a huge delay of up to a second, and I can't set/access the position of the file.

I've looked into OpenTK and OpenAL but that seems way too complex to figure out.

Does anyone have any ideas?

THANKS!

Oh and worst case scenario I could also deal with playing WAV or OGG files instead, and if the play timing is accurate enough I wouldn't need access to the position of the audio.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAL may seem complicated, but it sounds like the best solution to your problem.  There's plenty out there on it, though most examples might be in other languages, but the API is the same.  Perhaps [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739306/playing-audio-in-net-c-sharp) has some solutions as well.